# Autosize HTML table cell height based on content when rowspan is involved

Tags: html, html-table, cell

Is there a way to autosize HTML table height based on content? Also if it's a cell (or cells) next to a neighbor cell with multiple rowspans.

E.g. if I have a table like this (cell on the right has Rowspan="2" and height of the cell content = 600px, in each cell on the left height of the cell content = 150px):

[image: Cells evenly spaces]

there is a gap between 2 cell consents on the left because cells themselves autosized their height. I'd like it to look like this:

[image: Cell height adjusted to content]

Where top cells automatically collapse to cell content height. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: are you using jquery( or any other javascript framework) or only javascript?

Comment: Plain JS. But I don't think direct height assignment will resize the cell in this scenario

Comment: direct cell alignment will do, but the problem is, if you know how many cell there will be (to write the code) or the cells are created dynamically.

Comment: Table/cells are created dynamically (from server-side code) but that shouldn't be a problem. But it looks like height assignment doesn't work, even when I tried something direct like

    $get('idOfTd').height='100px';

or

    $get('idOfTd').style.height='100px';

it had no effect on cell height visually (DOM did reflect property change).

Comment: I figured that by giving content's control negative bottom margin I can bring cells below it up (e.g. $get('xContentDiv').marginBottom = '-100px') but I cannot figure out correct value for the margin - it looks like it changes depending on number of cells in the column

Comment: Also I see that Chrome displays layout correctly already without any changes needed. But the rest (FireFox, IE) have the issue

Comment: Tried a hack by setting TD height to 1 - didn't work either. Any help is appreciated

Comment: at the end of the your page create a javascript code and let it do it for you:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sets the last row of cells to the correct height ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/jrut4/)):

```
function grow(td) {
    var table, target, high, low, mid;

    td = $(td);
    table = td.closest('table');
    target = table.height();
    low = td.height();

    // find initial high
    high = low;
    while (table.height() <= target) {
        td.height(high *= 2);
    }

    // binary search!
    while (low + 1 < high) {
        mid = low + Math.floor((high - low) / 2);
        td.height(mid);
        if (table.height() > target) {
            high = mid;
        } else {
            low = mid;
        }
    }

    td.height(low);
}

$('tr:last-child td').each(function() { grow(this); });
```

​
It should be trivial to convert this into plain JavaScript.

---

**Update:** For more complicated tables, you'll want to replace the last line with this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/jrut4/8/)):

```
$.each($('td').get().reverse(), function() { grow(this); });
```

​
The idea is to call `grow()` on every cell, starting with the last row and working upwards.

Comment: Looks promising, thanks! Will test it when I get to my dev laptop

Comment: Still experimenting with moving this to plain vanilla JS. Will this work if the table layout is a bit more complicated? It will always have 2 columns, but some cells can span both columns and not one but more cells can span multiple rows.

Comment: Thanks again for the brilliant solution. If anybody need a plain JavaScript version, I posted it at http://codecorner.galanter.net/2012/06/13/html-table-rowspan-autofit-spanned-cells-to-content/

Answer (score 1):

considering table id="mytable" it would be:

```
    $("#mytable").find("td").each(function(){ 

    var ContentHeight = $($(this).html()).height();
    $(this).height(ContentHeight);

 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. We do not use jQuery; I could do the same in the plain vanilla JavaScript, but I don't think simply assigning height value to the cell will work in this scenario. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Hi, do you by any chance have any update on this issue? I am stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

at the end of the your page create a javascript code and let it do it for you:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementById("idOfTd").style.height="100px";
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it actually visibly reduces height of the top left cell in IE or FireFox?

Comment: If it's not too much trouble - could you please attach a working sample? Including HTML markup of the table with rowspan and the code that reduces height of the top cell next to the spanned one. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think it better create like this http://jsfiddle.net/miqdad/w9QYB/

Comment: Yes, I've come across table-in-table solution, but currently the table layout is generated by server-side code and changing it involves not a small effort. I need to find a client-side solution that works with existing layout.

Comment: Can you please post the code which you getting in browser view source

Comment: Hi, the basic one looks something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/r3pLC, it will always have 2 columns, but can be more complicated - some cells can span 2 columns, more other cells can span multiple rows etc. The requirement if at any point cell spans multiple rows - it's neighbors' content must be top-aligned and close together